# Объединение [crypt] и [криптография]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Следует ли объединить метки [crypt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crypt) (41 вопрос) и [криптография](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%8f) (265 вопросов), так как, по сути, они значат одно и то же?

Лучше оставить, наверно, [криптография](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%8f), так как с этой меткой больше вопросов.